# Cos'è un "mazzarello"?

Tags: word-meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> La città – cosí sudicia e pittoresca nei pressi del porto – era diventata piú bella. Sparite le case di legno fatiscenti, le folle stracciate e gli ambulanti. Sparita la gente bracalona che parlava dialetti vagamente familiari, la miriade di ragazzini che giocavano a biglie negli scoli della fogna. Ora ai lati della strada c’erano palazzi con facciate di marmo, e i pedoni portavano bombette e **mazzarelli** da passeggio di canna di bambú.

Potreste spiegarmi il significato di "mazzarello" in questo passaggio? Non l'ho trovato sui dizionari che ho consultato. Dal contesto sembra si tratti di qualche tipo di bastone.

Comment: In generale in napoletano `-riello` indica un diminutivo. In questo caso [di mazza](http://www.vesuvioweb.com/it/wp-content/uploads/Giuseppe-Giacco-Vocabolario-napoletano-vesuvioweb.pdf), quindi bastone. Come immagine la parola mi rievoca le processioni di un tempo aperte da una banda musicale, diretta e capitanata dal direttore che in mano teneva un bastone (con un pomello in capo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Questa fonte](https://books.google.it/books?id=ztd7DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=mazzarello%20bastone&source=bl&ots=IxLWxWNJG1&sig=ACfU3U3DmduoEiZs8LycJ_daSjq_M89l2g&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi7n5GFpIvgAhXP_KQKHZxhCrIQ6AEwDnoECAUQAQ#v=onepage&q=mazzarello%20bastone&f=false) parlando dell’origine del cognome Mazzarella dice che *mazzarella* è:

> Lungo bastone con capocchia adoperato dai butteri oppure l’appellativo
>   *mazzarello* bacchetta, arnese per sostenere il ferro nel fare la calza.

Quindi direi che l’intuizione è corretta: indica una specie di bastone da passeggio.

Answer (score 1):

Ho trovato il vocabolo su questo [*Vocabolario delle parole del dialetto napoletano*](https://books.google.es/books?id=QgtZAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA13-PA142&lpg=RA13-PA142&dq=mazzarello&source=bl&ots=SE5rc65g2A&sig=PBImfbYjsrGY8V1nXKitEYPIl1M&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIqbrC4rvfAhWzgM4BHeo4DVUQ6AEwBHoECAMQAQ#v=onepage&q=mazzarello&f=false), come sinonimo di un termine napoletano, "spruoccolo". Su [*Wikipedia*](https://nap.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spruoccolo) si può leggere che uno "spruoccolo" è

> nu bastunciello 'e lignammo, piccerella parte de rammo

cioè, un bastoncino di legno o una piccola parte di un ramo, come si spiega anche [qui](http://neapolitansdoitbetter.altervista.org/addo-arrivammo-mettimmo-o-spruoccolo/?doing_wp_cron=1548498394.2443249225616455078125):

> Va subito spiegato che lo “spruoccolo” altro non è che un bastoncino di legno, o anche un rametto secco

Quindi si tratterebbe effettivamente di un bastoncino, probabilmente in legno (non so fino a che punto arrivi la sinonimia).